# Optimised way to find all integers p and q such that 2^p*3^q has a given decimal length

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic

> Find all possible combinations of `a` and `b` such that the number of decimal digits of `r` is a given number `N`.

Comment: Do brute force, then optimize.  Probably no easy solution.

Comment: @duffymo I have respect for your comment .. but I have used stackOverflow Platform for not getting BruteForce solution. Kindly suggest If there is better solution or else let other to put their views on it.

Comment: There is none that I know of.  You'll do better here if you post the solution you have and ask for improvements.

Comment: @duffymo Ok I am updating my Question.

Comment: Still no code from you. Not a helpful modification.

Comment: @duffymo The obvious solution is `O(N^2)`.  There is a `O(N)` algorithm.  (Where those are counts of operations, large integer operations can themselves be slow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem generalizes naturally to the question of finding all `p, q` such that `2^p * 3^q` is between a `minimum` and a `maximum`.  Where `min = 10^N` and `max = 10^(N+1) - 1`.

I will talk through the algorithm, and also talk through the special case of length 2 as an example.

The first step is to generate an array of powers of 2 until you pass `max`.  In other words `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]`.  Any time you see something of the form `2^p` it can then be calculated with an array lookup.

Next we find `min_p` and `max_p` such that for `min_p <= p <= max_p` we have `min <= 2^p <= max`.  We do that by searching backwards from the end of our array until we find `max_p` then backwards more to `min_p`.  In our case, `min_p = 4` and `max_p = 6`.

Now we start with `q=0` and proceed as follows.

```
q = 0
pow = 1
while 0 <= max_p:
    for p between min_p and max_p:
        add (p, q) to the answer

    pow *= 3
    q += 1
    # We want min_p to stop at 0
    while 0 < min_p and min < pow * 2^(min_p - 1):
        min_p -= 1
    # max_p going below 0 is how we know to stop.
    while 0 <= max_p and max < pow * 2^max_p:
        max_p -= 1
```

In our example this would work as follows:

```
min_p = 4, max_p = 6
q = 0
add (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0) to answer
q = 1
min_p = 2
max_p = 5
add (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1) to answer
q = 2
min_p = 0
max_p = 3
add (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2) to answer
q = 3
min_p = 0
max_p = 1
add (0, 3), (1, 3) to answer
q = 4
min_p = 0
max_p = 0
add (0, 4) to answer
q = 5
min_p = 0
max_p = -1
finish
```

Our answer now is:

```
(4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1),
(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (0, 4)
```

Which is to say:

```
16, 32, 64, 12, 24, 48, 96, 18, 36, 72, 27, 54, 81
```

Comment: can u please tell what are the values of max and min. ? for example 2

Comment: I think (0, 2) will not be in answer.

Answer (score 1):

2^p * 3^q = 10^x for some x

10^(log10(2)*p) * 10^(log10(3)*q) = 10^x

So

x = log10(2)*p + log10(3)*q

and you know that x must be between N - 1 (including) and N (excluding)

So you have must find all p, q that:

N - 1 <= log10(2)*p + log10(3)*q < N

Then you need to find possible minimum and maximum for p and q and than you can BF using loop through all p,q or more greedy solution if you analyze and filter inappropriate values

Answer (score 0):

Won't a log(N)/log(3) algorithm suffice?

First find N, the number of decimal digits.

```
int count_p = 0
while (N%2 == 0) {
   count_p += 1;
   N /= 2;
}

int count_q = 0
while (N%3 == 0) {
   count_q += 1;
   N /= 3;
}
```

This gives you p and q.

Comment: This does not address the given problem.  As best I can tell, this code is built to find how many times 2 and 3 will divide `N`; this is a very different problem.